# Excel double IF statement: How to write function correctly for calender?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I need to write a function that follows the instructions below:

In cell B6 enter an if() function that checks to see if the contents of the cell to its left is blank. If it is, then execute another if() function that checks cell $E$27 to see if it is B5. If it is, then make the cell, 1; If it is not make the cell a blank (“”). If A6 is not a blank then insert one more than the content of cell A6.

Year is set to B1

$E$27 is a call to a three letter abbrevation of the day given for instance "Sun" on D28.

B27 is the number of April (4).

the formula for D28 is:

```
=DATE(B1,B27,1)
```

the formula for E27 is:

```
=TEXT(D27,"ddd")
```

The formula for A6 is:

```
=IF(E27="Sun",1,"")
```

The best I could come up with for B6:

```
=IF(A6=0,IF($E$27=B5,1,""),A6+1)
```

I get returned a #VALUE! error if the year is set to 2023, but if the year is set to 2018 the function works fine. What is the correct way to write this function?

Comment: `I get returned a #VALUE! error if the year is set to 2023` - where is the year here?

Comment: the year is set to B1

Comment: What has B1 to do with your formula?

Comment: The goal is to tell what day of the month starts with 1, and able to change with different years.

Answer (score 0):

This returns '1' in a blank worksheet:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A6),IF($E$27=B5,1,""),A6+1)
```

(A6 is blank => [second if] E27 = B5 [nothing for both] => [second if true statement] 1.

The ISBLANK() function does exactly what the name suggests; checks whether the cell is blank. However, I get the same result (1) when using A6=0 as the test.

Comment: When i try to put "1" on the [value_if_true] spot for the first if statement i get the error "there is a problem with the formula".

Comment: Did you copy my answer? The "1" should go in the [value if true] position for the second if statement.